# Where exactly is the London Shoreditch National Express Coach Stop?

Tags: buses, london, locate-this

For some reason the rubbish website shows that the Shoreditch stop is just off the Ivory Coast. Any idea where it actually is?

Comment: Which website are you referring to, just out of interest? And which route is this stop on? On the way to one of the airports?

Comment: My hunch is that that bit of sea is at 0 latitude, 0 longitude, someone forgot to put in an entry, and the website isn't smart enough to spot that case and skip the map...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The National Express website is presumably the one you mean, where it [shows it off the African coast](http://coach.nationalexpress.com/nxbooking/stop-location-map?location=London%20Shoreditch).

However, if you look further down the page, it says:

> London (Shoreditch)
>
> Bethnal Green Rd (to Stansted Airport: Stop J
>
> opp Overground Stn; or
>
> from Stansted: Stop K)

[Bethnal Green road on Google Maps](https://maps.google.ca/maps?q=bethnal%20green%20overground%20station&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a&channel=fflb&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=en&sa=N&tab=wl) clearly shows the road  running west-east, with the Overground station indicated on the same map.

Hope that helps!

Comment: thank you very much just to clear that up. On the stop finder which presumably is meant to make it clearer, it doesn't call the stop 'shoreditch' http://coach.nationalexpress.com/nxbooking/stop-finder

Comment: That's the Bethnal Green stop, at the other end of Bethnal Green Road.

Answer (score 4):

From the [coach tracker](http://coachtracker.nationalexpress.com/stops/900057878/London_Shoreditch_Bethnal_Green_Rd_Shoreditch) section of the website, you can see a map with a photo. It's a [Google map](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=51.523668,-0.076491&ll=51.523364,-0.076523&spn=0.00265,0.003321&num=1&t=h&z=18), and Google shows the bus stop on the map.

The [A9](http://coachtracker.nationalexpress.com/routes/A9/I/London_Liverpool_Street_Stn-Stansted_Airport) coach stops on Bethnal Green Road, just north of the [Shoreditch High Street](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shoreditch_High_Street_railway_station) Overground station. The stop is at the very end of Bethnal Green Road as it terminates onto Shoreditch High Street. SDC is the first stop north of Whitechapel on the way towards Dalston Junction.

The A9 stops on the north side of the street on its way east to Bethnal Green and onwards to Stanstead. It stops on the south side of the street (station side) on its way to Liverpool Street and Whitechapel.